# rewrite url using accents characters with wamp server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, special-characters

I'm here to ask about a strange behaviour of Apache with accents:

this rule works just fine

```
RewriteRule ^([èéìòùa-zA-Z0-9_\-\s]*)$     index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

but if i dare to add an `'à'`

```
RewriteRule ^([àèéìòùa-zA-Z0-9_\-\s]*)$     index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

Apache loses his mind (Yes, I can hear you reading this with the Joker voice)

Can anyone explain this to me?

UPDATE: Error log

```
[Wed Nov 12 12:49:43 2014] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Wed Nov 12 12:49:43 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win64) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0g PHP/5.3.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 12 12:49:43 2014] [notice] Server built: Sep 24 2011 19:57:51
[Wed Nov 12 12:49:43 2014] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3304
[Wed Nov 12 12:49:43 2014] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Wed Nov 12 12:49:44 2014] [notice] Child 3304: Child process is running
[Wed Nov 12 12:49:44 2014] [notice] Child 3304: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Nov 12 12:49:44 2014] [notice] Child 3304: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Nov 12 12:49:44 2014] [notice] Child 3304: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Wed Nov 12 12:49:44 2014] [notice] Child 3304: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

Comment: So what happens when you added `à`? Apache loses his pants?

Comment: How does apache lose its mind? what's the error logs say?

Comment: It gives an Internal Server Error message (ERROR 500).

Updated question with server log.

Comment: Assuming htaccess rewrite rules has the `u` (unicode) flag, try `^([[:alpha:]0-9_\-\s]*)$`

Comment: Or try adding `B` in the flagset. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags

Comment: Nothing seems to change using both flags.
I've tried the same modrewrite on a centOS server (apache version 2.2.3) and everything works fine.
Or a Wamp setting, since I've tried even there.
Maybe is just an option of the Apache server or version (v 2.2.1)

Comment: With which charset is your .htaccess encoded? Why don't you just use a larger pattern like `.*` or `[^/]+` and let your index.php handle this? Even if we admit it works with your .htaccess encoded in ISO-8859-1: what will happen if the client request is UTF-8 encoded? (or vice-versa) Else just try to use code escapes (eg: `é` in ISO-8859-1 is `\xE9` ; `\xC3\xA9` in UTF-8 but you can't use a class anymore as this kind of code point is not encoded on a single byte)

Comment: I've already tried with the escaped codes while using u and B flags but i didn't set the default encoding of the htaccess file (my bad)... I'll check this tip as soon as I'll be back on that project. Thank you